# Parsing and storing records in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
00000;Name blah blah blah;02;13
00032;I don't care;01;44
00123;Hello how are you;02;28
00154;Random text;03;12
```

I only care about the first two records:

```
00000 Name blah blah blah
00032 I don't care
```

and so on. So I thought I could use the split function in Java to get the data. (Anyone with a better idea?) Something like this:

```
String linea = rEntrada.readLine();
String delimitador = "[;]";
String[] tokens = null;
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
    tokens = linea.split(delimitador);
}
```

This seems to only store the last record. When I do:

```
for (String token : tokens){
    logger.info("Token: " + token);
}
```

I get:

```
Token: 00154
Token: Random text
Token: 03
Token: 12
```

What am I doing wrong? As I said, I only want each line's first two fields and later I'll want to use them to do several inserts to a database. What would be a good data structure? I'm trying to become a great coder, so any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have already your data parsed. Why don't you just take first two strings from the array, you already have? `logger.info("first token: " + tokens[0] + " second token: " + tokens[1]);`

Comment: You always get the last record because you're overwriting the tokens variable in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop, you area not adding the results of each line to the array, you are replacing the previous results with the new ones, so when you get to the end, only the last one is there!

```
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
    tokens = linea.split(delimitador);
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
List<String[]> token = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
    tokens.add(linea.split(delimitador));
}

for (String [] token: tokens) {
  System.out.println(token[0] + ":" token[1]);
}
```

Of course depending on how large it is and if there are memory concerns you might want to actively remove the additional unused information.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a holder class with only those two fields you want and add that object to arraylist.

Example:

```
Holder
{
int firstAttribute;
String secondAttribute;
//Get/Set methods
}

String[] tokens = null;
List<Holder> list = new ArrayList<Holder>();
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
    tokens = linea.split(delimitador);
    Holder hObj = new Holder();
    hObj.setFirstAttribute(tokens[0]);
    hObj.secondAttribute(tokens[1]);
    list.add(hObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
   tokens = linea.split(delimitador);
}
```

This will keep reading the lines from the file and splitting them. In each iteration you will have one line worth of tokens in `tokens`,  but at the following iteration the reference `tokens` will be used to point to the tokens of the new line read. When the loop is exited, in `tokens` remains the data from the last line read.

You either

a) Just avoid the `while` and read twice the line with `readLine` (and after each line, process and store the tokens)

b) Process the tokens inside the loop, so you process each line and not the only one.

To test my point, add the log inside the `while` loop.

Comment: I was referring to this in my answer but you were faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Record {
    String number;
    String text;

    public Record(String number, String text) {
        super();
        this.number = number;
        this.text = text;
    }   
}

class Parser{

    int maxLines=2;

    public List<Record> parseFile(InputStream in){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();
        String line = null;     
        int curLine=0;
        while(curLine<maxLines && (line=scanner.nextLine())!=null){
            String[] split = line.split(";");               
            list.add(new Record(split[0], split[1]));
            curLine++;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You could have printed the tokens inside while loop.

String linea = rEntrada.readLine();
String delimitador = "[;]";
String[] tokens = null;
while ((linea = rEntrada.readLine()) != null){
 tokens = linea.split(delimitador);

 for (String token : tokens)
  {
   logger.info("Token: " + token);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the line separator in your file, it might be that you have it only after "00123;Hello how are you;02;28", thus second call to readLine() would return the "00154;Random text;03;12"

Otherwise, paste working example, as it seems you are looping to the end of file.